# Build VP8 codec for iOS

Tags: ios, voip, pjsip, vp8

I want to build VP8 video codec for iOS platform which can supported with PJSIP library. I am using PJSIP library version 2.6. Is there any patches available which can be used to build VP8 codec or any other code is required in iOS PJSIP.

Answer (score 1):

Pjsip support VP8, VP9 in version 2.10
https://github.com/pjsip/pjproject/releases/tag/2.10